# How to assess the rationality of real-life decisions?

Tags: measurement, methodology, decision-making, bias, rationality

I am looking for scales that measure the extent to which the process by which a person arrived at a real-life decision conformed to the principles of decision theory. I am specifically interested in questions that screen for established cognitive biases in decision-making such as temporal discounting, the availability bias, or the focussing illusion. Do you have any recommendations?